# Sqlserver Table Time field constraint

Tags: sql-server-2005, constraints

In SqlServer 2005 I have a table with a TimeOfDay field that is a varchar(5). I want to limit the field value to valid times only (13:40,2:20). This is what I have so far

```
ALTER TABLE tbl ADD CONSTRAINT ck
CHECK (TimeOfDay like '[1-2][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]' )
```

I want the constraint to allow the first digit to be optional, but not having much luck.

Comment: hrm good point. That way people won't type 1:30 and think it means 13:30.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to disallow "times" such as `29:99`

```
ALTER TABLE tbl ADD CONSTRAINT ck
CHECK (
TimeOfDay like  '[0-9]:[0-5][0-9]' OR
TimeOfDay like '1[0-9]:[0-5][0-9]' OR
TimeOfDay like '2[0-3]:[0-5][0-9]'
)
```

Have you considered storing as `datetime` with the date part set to 1 Jan 1900?

Comment: storing the date is fugly since its not used.

Comment: @Kenoyer130 - Agreed (this is better in SQL Server 2008 with the `time` datatype) but if you need to sort or work out time differences storing in datetime makes things easier.

Answer (score 2):

```
ALTER TABLE tbl ADD CONSTRAINT ck 
CHECK (
    (LEN(TimeOfDay) = 5 and TimeOfDay like '[1-2][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]')
        or (LEN(TimeOfDay) = 4 and TimeOfDay like '[0-9]:[0-9][0-9]')
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER TABLE tbl ADD CONSTRAINT ck 
CHECK (
    TimeOfDay like '[1-2][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]' 
    OR TimeOfDay like '[0-9]:[0-9][0-9]'
)
```